# Is there a way to use form_for without the enclosing <form> tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I want to use

```
<%= form_for(@modelname) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :foo %>
  <%= f.text_field :foo %>
<% end %>
```

And get only the inner HTML, without the enclosing  tag. Is it possible?

Comment: why do you want to do that? Its not possible via method parameters but maybe we can solve your original problem.

Comment: Do you happen to be using this for rendering a partial form to be swapped out using AJAX? I ended up using `fields_for` for exactly that purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that what you are looking for is [fields_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for).

```
<%= fields_for @model do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :foo %>
  <%= f.text_field :foo %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, i will add fields with AJAX only if a select has a certain value.